# iOS and OS X Photos.app - duplicate photos

Tags: photos, photos.app, photo-stream

when adding new photos to my OS X **Photos.app** and afterwards sync my iPhone with my Mac I see every photo I just added twice on the iPhone: One synced via iTunes and the other one via Photostream. Once I delete the photos in the photostream there are no duplicates anymore.

I'm using most recent versions of OS X, iOS, Photos.app, Photostream activated, iCloud photo Library NOT activated on all devices.

Is there any solution to get rid of the duplicates without deleting them in the Photostream? Doesn't iOS notice? The solution I would prefer is using photostream only "one-way" from iPhone to my Mac. I remember an option in the good old iPhoto.app making this possible, which is not present any more in the new Photos.app, as far as I know. By "one-way" I mean that only new photos I take on my iPhone are uploaded to the Photostream, but not photos I add to the Photos.app on my Mac. Is there a way to do that?

I'm curious on your ideas on this. Thanks in advance!

Sascha

Answer (score 1):

If you have activated Photostream, why do you use photo sync by iTunes? Just turn it off. And check setting about HDR version of your shots. May be you just see original and HDR version of shot?

Comment: I sync the photos via iTunes, because I regularly delete pictures in the photostream which have been uploaded by the Photos.app on OS X, because I only want to have the photos i took with my iPhone in it.